# Complex conversion to Python Complex

Tags: python, c++, std, cython, complex-numbers

I'm currently writing a wrapper for a C++ project that use `std::complex<double>`, available in cython as `libcpp.complex.complex[double]`.

However there is no implicit conversion between this and Python complex, I'm trying to find the best way to do this conversion.

The obvious is to use

```
cdef libcpp.complex.complex[double] x = ...
X = complex(x.real(),x.imag()
```

And

```
cdef complex Y = ...
cdef libcpp.complex.complex[double] y = libcpp.complex.complex[double](Y.real, Y.imag)
```

And

```
cdef libcpp.complex.complex[double] z
cdef complex Z = ...
z.real(Z.real)
z.imag(Z.imag)
```

But is there a better way, preferably to make cython do the conversion automatically.

For one this occurs in some `cpdef` functions, and I would like to avoid using Python complex in calls from cython for improved speed.

However as far as I can tell cython can't do this conversion implicitly, and thus I can't avoid using the Python complex for code that can be called from Python or C++.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality will be released in the next version of Cython.

https://github.com/cython/cython/commit/2c3c04b25620c437ce41d7851e7581eb1f0c313c